# API to publish articles on Joomla and Drupal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, drupal, joomla

Do Joomla and Drupal provide any kind of APIs to publish articles?

I have Ruby on Rails application for content authoring and need to publish articles to different sites which are runs on Joomla and Drupal.

Comment: Can you please define what you mean by publish? Also both Joomla and Drupal have separate sites on Stackexchange.com and you probably will get more advice on them.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done via for example a CLI script running on a Joomla site using the articles Model.

One suggestion would be to publish an RSS or XML feed that you can then import periodically via a Joomla CLI script. An example CLI script is given below. Points to note:

- In the below example data is imported from a CSV file you would have to modify this for whatever your data source is.
- The catid is hardcoded - you may wish to post your articles to different categories in which case you would need to do more work to potentially look up category IDs.
- It doesn't include tags etc
- Is only a solution for Joomla not Drupal

I could go on but this is a Q&A site not a consultancy opportunity...;-)

```
<?php

/**
 * @package    Joomla.Cli
 *
 * @copyright  Copyright (C) 2005 - 2015 Open Source Matters, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * @license    GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
 */
// Initialize Joomla framework
        const _JEXEC = 1;

// Load system defines
if (file_exists(dirname(__DIR__) . '/defines.php'))
{
  require_once dirname(__DIR__) . '/defines.php';
}

if (!defined('_JDEFINES'))
{
  define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(__DIR__));
  require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/defines.php';
}

// Get the framework.
require_once JPATH_LIBRARIES . '/import.legacy.php';

// Bootstrap the CMS libraries.
require_once JPATH_LIBRARIES . '/cms.php';

/**
 * Cron job to import data into articles
 *
 * @since  2.5
 */
class ImportArticlesCron extends JApplicationCli
{

  /**
   * Entry point for the script
   *
   * @return  void
   *
   * @since   2.5
   */
  public function doExecute()
  {

    // Import articles model
    JControllerForm::addModelPath(JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . '/components/com_content/models');

    // Get an instance of the content model
    $model = $this->getModel('Article', 'ContentModel');

    // This example is using a csv file but there's no reason you couldn't import an XML file here
    while (($line = fgetcsv($handle, 0, $delimiter = '|')) !== FALSE)
    {
      $data = array();
      $data['introtext'] = '';
      $data['fulltext'] = $output;
      $data['id'] = '';
      $data['state'] = ($line[1] == 'True') ? 1 : 0;
      $data['title'] = iconv("ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8//TRANSLIT", $line[3]);
      $data['created'] = $line[2];
      $data['catid'] = 38;
      $data['language'] = 'en-GB';
      $data['metadesc'] = '';
      $data['metakey'] = '';

      //$data['publish_up'] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($line[14]));
      //$data['publish_down'] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($line[15]));
      $model = $this->getModel('Article', 'ContentModel');

      if (!$model->save($data))
      {
        $error = $model->getError();
      }
    }
  }

}

JApplicationCli::getInstance('ImportArticlesCron')->execute();
?>
```

Comment: I have no idea about Joomla/Drupal and PHP in general. I am looking for some pointers which can help me to explore in right direction.

We don't have access to any site though. But I can ask the site owners to install/update something which is required to make this working.

Comment: I edited my answer with a possible solution for the Joomla site. I can show you an example CLI script of you think it might work for you.

Comment: Yes please show me the example so that I can understand it.

Comment: Just set up a Joomla or Drupal site locally.   A CLI script can definitely use the APIs to publish if by publishing you mean changing that specific field.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the question for Joomla is no, there's no web API to publish articles from remote.

I never had to implement such a solution so I don't have a proven answer.
Being a developer, my first thought would be to build a custom API component. 
Maybe, before that, I would look into the [JED](http://extensions.joomla.org) to see if someone already did it.

Comment: Then what alternate solution can used for publishing articles on Joomla?

Comment: Edited my answer with possible solutions.

Comment: I tried to search on JED. There is only one extension which may be useful to us is Jbackend. Is it reliable? Is there any free plugin?

Comment: If I had known reliable extension, I would have reported them in my answer. Unfortunately I don't have any more suggestions for you.

Comment: Do you mean there is no REST API in your answer? OF course there are APIs for publishing, but to make it work with REST you have to write an application to provide the interface.

Comment: I added an example which should get you some of the way there at least with Joomla. Hope it helps.